# Identify numbers, in a large data string, that are prefixed to an alphabet upto 2 positions in between other characters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, list, data-cleaning

I have a string containing thousands of lines of this data without line break (only a few lines shown for readability with line break)

```
5BengaluruUrban4598962MSARICoughBreathlessnessDM23.07.2020atGovernmenthospital
7DakshinaKannada4786665FSARICoughDMHTN23-07-2020atPrivatehospital
```

Format is

> (entry number)(district)(patient number)(age)(gender)(case of)(symptoms)(comorbidity)(date of death)(place of death)

without spaces, or brackets.

Problem : **The data i want to collect is age.**
However i cant seem to find a way to single out the age since its clouded by a lot of other numbers in the data. I have tried various iterations of count, limiting it to 1 to 99, separating the data etc, and failed.

My Idea : Since the gender is always either 'M'/'F', and the two numbers before the gender is the age. Isolating the two numbers before the gender seems like an ideal solution.

```
xxM
xxF
```

My Goal : I would like to collect all the xx numbers irrespective of gender and store them in a list. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
input_str = '5BengaluruUrban4598962MSARICoughBreathlessnessDM23.07.2020atGovernmenthospital7DakshinaKannada4786665FSARICoughDMHTN23-07-2020atPrivatehospital'

ages = [found[-3:-1] for found in re.findall('[0-9]+[M,F]', input_str, re.I)]
print(ages)
# ['62', '65']
```

This works fine with the sample but if there are districts starting with 'M/F' then entry number will be collected as well.

A workaround is to match exactly seven digits (if the patient number is always 5 digits and and the age is generally 2 digits).

```
ages = [found[-3:-1] for found in re.findall(r'\d{7}[M,F]', input_str, re.I)]
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. The patient number goes from 1 to the digits it is today (lot of cases) hence the workaround you included only worked till a couple of thousand patients. There is a district with an M, but i figured out a way to exclude them from the  results.

Comment: of course it is easier if you have a list of ALL possible districts.. or all possible conditions for that matter

Answer (score 1):

With the structure you gave I've built a `dict` of reg expressions to match components.  Then put this back into a `dict`

There are ways I can imagine this will not work

1. if age < 10,  only 1 digit so you will pick up a digit of *patient number*
2. there maybe strings that don't match the `re` expressions which will mean odd results

It's the most structured way I can think to go....

```py
import re
data = "5BengaluruUrban4598962MSARICoughBreathlessnessDM23.07.2020atGovernmenthospital7DakshinaKannada4786665FSARICoughDMHTN23-07-2020atPrivatehospital"

md = {
    "entrynum": "([0-9]+)",
    "district": "([A-Z,a-z]+)",
    "patnum_age": "([0-9]+)",
    "sex": "([M,F])",
    "remainder": "(.*)$"
}

data_dict = {list(md.keys())[i]:tk
 for i, tk in
    enumerate([tk for tk in re.split("".join(md.values()), data) if tk!=""])
}

print(f"Assumed age:{data_dict['patnum_age'][-2:]}\nparsed:{data_dict}\n")
```

**output**

```
Assumed age:62
parsed:{'entrynum': '5', 'district': 'BengaluruUrban', 'patnum_age': '4598962', 'sex': 'M', 'remainder': 'SARICoughBreathlessnessDM23.07.2020atGovernmenthospital7DakshinaKannada4786665FSARICoughDMHTN23-07-2020atPrivatehospital'}
```